# What is "electrum style signature"?

Tags: signature, yellow-paper

In the Yellow paper, appendix F "Signing Transactions", (BYZANTIUM VERSION f72032b - 2018-05-04 to be specific), it says:

> The method of signing transactions is similar to the ‘Electrum style signatures’ as defined by Arnaud et al. [2017], heading “Managing styles with Radium” in the bullet point list.

The paper then goes on about how ECDSA is used in Ethereum, but never clarifies any furthur about what "Electrum style" means or how it's applied in this circumstance.

Here is the full quote of [the mentioned section](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electrum#managing-styles-with-radium), retrieved at 27-07-2018:

> ## Managing styles with Radium
>
> We decided to use `radium` as the way to go to inject styles into components. By using the `E` instance provided by `import Electrum from 'electrum'`), components are automatically configured to use `radium` when *wrapped* like this:
>
> ```
> import Electrum from 'electrum';
> import _Button from './Button.component.js';
> import _Button$styles from './Button.styles.js';
> export const Button = Electrum.wrap ('Button', _Button, {styles: _Button$styles});
> ```
>
> See `electrum-theme` for an explanation of how style functions should
>   be defined. Style functions can have following signatures:
>
> - `() => ...` → a parameterless style function.
> - `(theme) => ...` → a style function, based on the theme.
> - `(theme, props) => ...` → a style function, based on the theme and on   the component properties. The component should implement a
>     *getter* named   `styleProps` which returns a hash with the meaningful properties.
>
> Multiple styles definitions can be exported as a *hash* of style
>   functions.
>
> ### Component with a single style function
>
> A component linked with a style definition consisting of a single
>   style function will expose following method and property:
>
> - `styles` → a *styles object* which can be set on DOM element `style`   properties; the styles object is compatible with Radium. It
>     exposes a   `with(s1, s2, ...)` function which can be used to obtain
>     an updated   *styles object* into which additional styles have been
>     merged.
> - `mergeStyles(s1, s2, ...)` → a *hash* containing the merged styles.
>
> ### Component with a multiple style functions
>
> A component linked with a style definition consisting of a multiple
>   style functions will expose following methods:
>
> - `getStyles(key)` → a *styles object* for the specified style definiton,   which can be set on DOM element `style` properties; the
>     styles object is   compatible with Radium. It exposes a `with(s1, s2,
>     ...)` function which   can be used to obtain an updated *styles
>     object* into which additional   styles have been merged.
> - `mergeStyles(key, s1, s2, ...)` → a *hash* containing the merged   styles for the specified style definition.
>
> Note that the signature of the methods are different from a component
>   with a single style function.

I know that transaction signature Ethereum is a triplet of `(v, r, s)`, but can't understand how any of the above description applies to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has also been brought up on the [github](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper/issues/704).

It appears that the citation was added in [this commit](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper/commit/570baa3e0a95e81d5b1025527ec9d9839ab7c9d0), and as you pointed out, it clearly has no relevance to the actual content. The "Electrum" referred to in the yellow paper is the Electrum light client for Bitcoin, while the citation points to some JS library.

I'm not exactly sure what is meant by "Electrum style signatures", but this phrase has been in the paper since the first draft so presumably it means something.

In my opinion, the whole line should just be deleted from the paper, and I will submit PR to do so.

Answer (score 1):

`pyethereum` was Python implementation of Ethreum, and it also had references to Electrum

> (v,r,s) is the raw Electrum-style signature of the transaction without the
> signature made with the private key corresponding to the sending account,
> with 0 <= v <= 3. From an Electrum-style signature (65 bytes) it is
> possible to extract the public key, and thereby the address, directly.

https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/blob/master/ethereum/transactions.py#L31

Yet in `electrum` code base, there's no explanations.

https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/blob/master/electrum/transaction.py

So similar, maybe in 2013-2014 it was clear what are those “electrum style signature”, but as time went the references where removed.

So if you find anything like Electrum within Ethereum, that means you look at old outdated stuff.